# TCP Error Code 10060 when sending request to Oracle Service Registry from Windows WCF Client

Tags: wcf

Hi All I get below error when sending request to OSR (Oracle Service Registry) from a Windows WCF Client.

"Could not connect to http://xxxx:xx/registry/uddi/inquiry TCP error code 10060: A Connection attempt failed vecause the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond HostIPAddress:Port."

the inner exception is:
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occured in method 'handleReturnMessage' of class 'realProxy'.

Env Details:
WCF Client installed on mutiple remote computers connected via broadband.
OSR installed on Linux box ( I don't have any control on this).

WCF Client details:
.NET Framewrok 3.5 Win Form app.
Client config file showing OSR endpoint and binding details.

```
     <basicHttpBinding>
 <binding name="basHTTPBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
 </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>


<client>
   <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basHTTPBinding" contract="XXXX" name="OSR" />
 </client>
```

Please let me know any of your thoughts on why this error occurs. Please note that this occurs intermitently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason most likely for this error could be network issue over VPN. We need to monitor the network availability on the prod site if we face such kind of issues.